# How to pass data from to other ViewControllers by multiple Segues

Tags: swift, segue, bundle

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "profile"? :
        if let destination = segue.destination as? Profile{
            destination.username = "demo"  
        }
        break
    case "contact"?:
            if let destination = segue.destination as? Contact{
                destination.email = "email1@xxxxx_com"                                      
            }
        break
    default:
        print("no segue has been called")
        break
    }

}
```

in other ViewControllers I have global variables like below :

```
class Profile: UIViewController {
var username = ""

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("username : ", username) 
}
```

**But when the Profile ViewController starts, the value of username stays empty!** means, all what I have updated, will be lost again and the variables will get again the original values!!!

**updated :**
Remark : the values which I want to edit are into Profile.swift, but the segue is connected to ProfileMain.swift. I use a container on the main ViewController "ProfileMain" like here on the screenshot image:
[screenshot1](https://monosnap.com/file/sOxeQZZMKWHJc4N7XVAvceoZvaUO4O)

Demo layout of Storyboard :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="13771" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="13772"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--ProfileMain-->
        <scene sceneID="y2Q-vO-42x">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="vZJ-mp-RUK" userLabel="ProfileMain" customClass="ProfileMain" customModule="Segue_with_Data" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="OXb-l2-lpG">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <containerView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="3k0-LA-yQx">
                                <rect key="frame" x="27" y="68" width="320" height="226"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="320" id="74O-jJ-2Oy"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="226" id="vwt-h9-yTg"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="R2w-XN-4gi" kind="embed" id="Wv6-xm-hP9"/>
                                </connections>
                            </containerView>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="3bp-10-M6F">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="375" height="40"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.57312941549999996" green="0.57311660050000002" blue="0.57311910389999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="RL2-dG-8Ax"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="20"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Close Profile">
                                    <color key="titleColor" red="0.1221005991" green="0.12947699430000001" blue="0.1412781179" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                </state>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="BtnCloseProfile:" destination="vZJ-mp-RUK" eventType="touchUpInside" id="XdI-21-0cF"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.49327188729999999" blue="0.47399842739999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="3bp-10-M6F" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="TFs-jh-JJy" secondAttribute="trailing" id="3mA-uw-h7K"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="3k0-LA-yQx" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="OXb-l2-lpG" secondAttribute="centerX" id="JKC-5A-PFW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="3bp-10-M6F" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="TFs-jh-JJy" secondAttribute="top" id="Ksn-Rt-FAW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="3k0-LA-yQx" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="3bp-10-M6F" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="TjK-LS-dPm"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="3bp-10-M6F" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="TFs-jh-JJy" secondAttribute="leading" id="lO3-oZ-h4E"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="TFs-jh-JJy"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="R5o-du-dms" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1055.2" y="117.39130434782609"/>
        </scene>
        <!--ProfileMain-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" userLabel="ProfileMain" customClass="ViewController" customModule="Segue_with_Data" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="A20-gr-1Kl">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" selectionStyle="blue" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="mycell" rowHeight="130" id="3wm-VQ-0zg" customClass="TableViewCell" customModule="Segue_with_Data" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="130"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="3wm-VQ-0zg" id="o3N-Ob-VA8">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="129.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="deW-A9-4Vv">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="35" width="375" height="30"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.610782767" green="0.66666668650000005" blue="0.5935411089" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="zpb-Fb-z4M"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="30"/>
                                                    <state key="normal" title="contact">
                                                        <color key="titleColor" red="0.1215686275" green="0.12941176469999999" blue="0.14117647059999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                    </state>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <segue destination="esD-m9-R0s" kind="show" identifier="contact" id="EhF-dw-AgB"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </button>
                                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="6ad-cu-gKu">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="73" width="375" height="30"/>
                                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.8828310989" green="0.93938174539999997" blue="0.95077186820000004" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                                    <constraints>
                                                        <constraint f***irstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="Gnm-SA-5vV"/>
                                                    </constraints>
                                                    <fontDescription*** key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="30"/>
                                                    <state key="normal" title="Profile">
                                                        <color key="titleColor" red="0.1221005991" green="0.12947699430000001" blue="0.1412781179" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                                    </state>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <segue destination="vZJ-mp-RUK" kind="show" identifier="profile" id="aFR-aF-KsG"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </button>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="deW-A9-4Vv" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="o3N-Ob-VA8" secondAttribute="top" constant="35" id="9FJ-oa-bNS"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="6ad-cu-gKu" secondAttribute="trailing" id="9q8-5C-CmJ"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="deW-A9-4Vv" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="o3N-Ob-VA8" secondAttribute="leading" id="Gmy-Ld-JrK"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="6ad-cu-gKu" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="deW-A9-4Vv" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="VRl-X7-BeG"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="6ad-cu-gKu" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="o3N-Ob-VA8" secondAttribute="leading" id="mLt-gu-lm7"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="deW-A9-4Vv" secondAttribute="trailing" id="rWS-2B-EE7"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableview1" destination="A20-gr-1Kl" id="3X7-ec-Qm2"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-98.400000000000006" y="118.29085457271366"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="dLf-bm-qRT">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="esD-m9-R0s" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="lpj-V1-Wi3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.8828310989" green="0.93938174539999997" blue="0.95077186820000004" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="r8n-lk-rjP"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="l65-qO-Rsu" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="642" y="117"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Profile-->
        <scene sceneID="YDY-De-cS5">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="R2w-XN-4gi" customClass="Profile" customModule="Segue_with_Data" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="25T-V9-Zvb">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="226"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Uub-nT-ZkO" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1056" y="710"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Force unwrap `segue.destination as! Profile` to reveal a design error. And I would never use optional `switch` cases

Comment: check if it goes through if statements. probably your assigning something wrong

Comment: **my code works fine for other ViewControllers**. but for Profile.swift not, because the Profile is as reference of ProfileMain.swift. if you check my demo storyboard code, you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

**Like this you can pass data from to other ViewControllers by multiple Segues**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "profile"
        {
           let destination = segue.destination as? Profile
            destination.username = "demo"  
        }

    if segue.identifier == "contact"
        {
           let destination = segue.destination as? Contact
            destination.email = "email1@xxxxx_com"  
        }

    }
```

Comment: switch case is way better then if else.

Comment: I have added more Details to my Question. check the screenshot pls

Comment: @user9212972, you want to edit value from ViewController "ProfileMain" right?. if yes then you want to send data in to  "ViewController" and "Profile"  swift filer right?.

Comment: I want to change the values from ViewController.swift. the values are in Profile.swift. (this is swift file of container). the segue connects ViewController with ProfileMain.  The code works fine if the values are directlly on ProfileMain. But I have to put them into Profile.swift

Comment: @user9212972, as I show in image that segue connected with ProfileMain.swift to Profile.swift. but you want to send data  ViewController.swift. to Profile.swift file. so you have to connect segue form ViewController.swift. to Profile.swift  controller.

Comment: but if I do that, i will see only a part of Profile. I see only the container which is a part of Profile. yes it works, but I have to see the hole Profile View

Comment: @user9212972, Profile ViewController not conneted with your main storeboard viewcontroller. as per i see in your screen short of main.storeboard

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to use Struct or Enum? I would advise you to use either of those.

In sourceVC, make this struct.

```
struct Segue {
    static let profile = "ProfileSegueID"
    static let contact = "ContactSegueID"
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch (segue.identifier, segue.destination, sender) {
    case (Segue.profile?, let vc as Profile):
        vc.username = "User Name"
    default: break
    }
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
}
```

Comment: the problem, after updating the values, these values will be lost when the viewController starts. I mean, we can edit the variable, but this variable will get its original value again when its ViewController starts. my code or your code can change the values of the Variable, allready tested, but why the update will be lost ? Atfirst I have thout the code does not work, but it works. the problem the Update will be lost :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to add breakpoints on lines, where you downcast segue.destination to subclass of UIViewController and check if downcast really happens.

But on my taste, it's better to perform force downcast (with "!" instead of "?") in this particular case, because you know exactly which subclass of UIViewController has to be in segue destination, and if there is wrong one, it's pretty good reason to explicitly crash an app.

Comment: if I do not use "?" and I use "!" I get error by going to Profile : the error said : **could not cast value of type ProfileMain (ox10c096840) to Profile** . Maybe bacause I use Container. check my screenshot in my update

Comment: Exactly, performing a segue you instantiate ProfileMain view controller and replace current view controller with it. When you put an instance of your Profile view controller in container, you probably store reference to it in your ProfileMain view controller, which you should use to interact with that instance.

And by the way, it seems to me that your app misses navigation controller

Comment: I have added breakpoint where I set the values, I see that I can set the values, but when the ViewController Profile starts, all values will be lost and they get the original values.